# DocuSign python (eg-03-python-auth-code-grant) authentication server problem

Tags: python, docusignapi

I am able to get on Docusign example page on my localhost:5000 fine but when I click on any of the 23 links it redirects me to localhost/ds/must_authenticate.
    - I click on “authenticate with DocuSign” link and it takes me to account-d.docusign.com/#/password
    -I enter my credentials and then it takes me appdemo.docusign.com/home
 I am trying to do one of the many examples from the DocuSign GitHub repo on https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-python-auth-code-grant . The only thing I have changed is In the ds_config to add my client_id, client_secret, signer_email, signer_name, session_secret, and I had to add /oauth on line 14 in the ds_config. Changing it from authorization_server": "https://account-d.docusign.com to authorization_server": "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth . The reason I added /oauth is because I get a client id error. The redirect URI I used in my integration key is http://localhost:5000/ds/callback. I guess I am having an issue with with the authorization_server. If I omit or keep brackets I get same results and can get past login. The url paths are : 127.0.0.1:5000 for homepage, then I click on any of the example links and get redirected to sign in page 127.0.0.1:5000/ds/must_authenticate, Then I click on the "authenticate with DocuSign" and get redirected to account.d.docusign.com/username#/password, then ""/password, then appdemo.docusign/authentication, then appdemo.docusign/redirect?to, then appdemo.docusign.com/home. I keep getting redirected to Docusign Homepage. If I take /oauth out of authorization server then I cant get past sign in page.

[DocuSignIntegrationKeyandRedirectURI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7tjU.png)

[OAuthSignInError DS_Config w/o brackets and w/o /oauth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsi38.png)

[DS_Config.py w/o brackets and w/o oauth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWRpj.png)

[DS_CONFIG.PY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q2za.png)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for submitting your question. On first glance, I see that your DS_Config.Py needs a couple of quick alterations. Can you try the following and let me know if you're still having issues with the OAuth flow?

1) Remove the { }'s from the config file. if you're listing your ds_client_id as {client_Id} it reads the {} as part of the ID, which will return an error indicating the key isn't properly registered with DocuSign. You'll want to remove the brackets from the first 5 variables in your config file.
2) Move the authorization_server back to the original URL (excluding '/oauth')

Let me know if that works for you, if you see another error on your side please reply with the exact error message with a screenshot if possible, then we can pick it up from there.

Comment: That would indicate that the returnURL that you're passing hasn't been registered with your Integration Key. Make sure the URI you're referencing (From your link its set to https://localhost:5050/ds/callback is also assigned specifically to the key. If you goto the Admin section of http://account-d.docusign.com and visit the API and Keys page, you should be able to confirm they match. If you're still seeing the error message, drop us an email at apiteam@docusign.com and we can take a closer look. In the meantime, please delete the link from your previous comment.

Comment: I could not find how to edit the previous comment so I just deleted the whole comment. Python Flask default is localhost:5000, so I don't know if it was a typo for 5050 but I tried it anyways. I will be emailing for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

A current workaround I have found is editing the views.py ds_token_ok function. On line 177, the ok boolean variables are not returning true. Not sure if it is a session problem. I edited the return statement to return True instead of ok, this has let me open all the links in the python application and run all the examples.

```
    def ds_token_ok(buffer_min=60):

   # :param buffer_min: buffer time needed in minutes
    #:return: true iff the user has an access token that will be good for #another buffer min


    ok = "ds_access_token" in session and "ds_expiration" in session
    ok = ok and (session["ds_expiration"] - timedelta(minutes=buffer_min)) > datetime.utcnow()
    #comment: was return ok but I am not able to run program. Problem in line 177
    return True
```

This is just a temporary solution to work in the sandbox.